# How to mount host directory after copying the files to the container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to copy the files of `src` folder to the container chowning them using `www-data` user and group, so in my `Dockerfile` I did:

```
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data src ./
```

when I access to the container I can see all the copied file but if I edit a file on the host, I'm not able to see the changes, so I have to rebuild the project using `docker-compose up --build -d`.

This is my `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  php-fpm:
    container_name: php_app
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    #volumes:
    #  - ./src:/var/www/html
```

if I comment out `volumes` I can work on the host directory and see the changes, but in this way I lose the `www-data` chown.

How can I manage such situation? Essentially I want:

- chown all files as `www-data`
- update files in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special feature to apply `chown` to mounted files. Leaving that and manual use of `chown` aside, you can make `php-fpm` workers to run with your `uid`. Here's how for `php:8.0.2-fpm-alpine` image (in other images path to config file can be different):

```sh
# Copy pool config out of a running container 
docker cp php_app:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf .

# Change user in config
sed "s/user = www-data/user = $(id -u)/" www.conf -i
# and/or change group
sed "s/group = www-data/group = $(id -g)/" www.conf -i
```

Now mount the edited config into the container using `volumes` in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  php-fpm:
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html # code
      - ./www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf # pool config
```

And restart the container.

Comment: I'm interested in the first solution, but I don't know how to implement it. Could you please show me an example? Thanks

Comment: @sfarzoso sure. Do you use one of the official php images as the base for your Dockerfile? If not, then please add the full Dockerfile to the question.

Comment: you can find the full dockerfile here: https://pastebin.com/DngaXa3i

Comment: yep, it is working fine! Many thanks. Just one thing: for some reason the `sed` command didn't worked for me, when I press enter, nothing happened. So I had to update the `www.conf` file manually and I set the root `id` which is 1001. I don't know if it's a good practice, I simply setted the same id of the docker container, so I suppose there should be any problem about that.

Comment: @sfarzoso that's because I made a mistake in the command, now fixed. Id 1001 is probably your user id, not root's (usually 0). In development environment any id should be fine and there is no problem in manual edit.